# Playing with Scrapi in Rails 3.. getting Segmentation Fault error / Abort Trap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping, web-scraping

What I've done so far..

```
sudo gem install scrapi

sudo gem install tidy
```

This didn't work because it didn't have the libtidy.dylib

So I did this :

```
sudo port install tidy

sudo cp libtidy.dylib /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/scrapi-1.2.0/lib/tidy/libtidy.dylib
```

Then I started following the simple railscast at : http://media.railscasts.com/videos/173_screen_scraping_with_scrapi.mov

Right after Mr. Bates finished the first save for `scrapitest.rb` , I tried to run this code :

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'scrapi'

scraper = Scraper.define do
  process "title", :page_name => :text
  result :page_name
end

uri = URI.parse("http://www.walmart.com/search/search-ng.do?search_query=lost+season+3&ic=48_0&search_constraint=0")
p scraper.scrape(uri)
```

With this code :

```
ruby scrapitest.rb
```

And it returned this error :

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/tidy-1.1.2/lib/tidy/tidybuf.rb:39: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]

Abort trap
```

Completely out of ideas..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue and then a follow-up issue where a seg fault would happen non-deterministically.

I followed the steps here - http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=10007&group_id=435&atid=1744

In tidy-1.1.2/lib/tidy/tidylib.rb:

1. Add this line to the 'load' method in Tidylib:

```
  extern "void tidyBufInit(void*)"
```

2. Define a new method called 'buf_init' in Tidylib:

```
  # tidyBufInit, using default allocator
  #
  def buf_init(buf)
    tidyBufInit(buf)
  end
```

Then, in tidy-1.1.2/lib/tidy/tidybuf.rb:

3. Add this line to the initialize method of Tidybuf below the malloc:

```
   Tidylib.buf_init(@struct)
```

so that is looks like this:

```
  # tidyBufInit, using default allocator
  #
  def buf_init(buf)
    @struct = TidyBuffer.malloc
    Tidylib.buf_init(@struct)
  end
```

4. For completeness, make Brennan's change by adding the allocator field to the TidyBuffer struct so that it looks like this:

```
  TidyBuffer = struct [
    "TidyAllocator* allocator",
    "byte* bp",
    "uint size",
    "uint allocated",
    "uint next"
  ]
```

Comment: Excellent post NatGordon. That really touched it up very very well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the error:
/opt/ruby/ruby-1.8.6/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/tidy-1.1.2/lib/tidy/tidybuf.rb:40: [BUG] Segmentation fault

It's because the data types don't match up in the latest Tidy (0.99) (/usr/include/buffio.h -     $Date: 2007/01/23
11:17:45 $ )

The resolution is to patch tidybuf.rb:

```
--- tidybuf.rb  2007-04-10 09:09:01.000000000 -0500
+++ tidybuf.rb.patched  2007-04-10 09:08:55.000000000 -0500
@@ -11,6 +11,7 @@
   # Mimic TidyBuffer.
   #
   TidyBuffer = struct [
+    "int* allocator",
     "byte* bp",
     "uint size",
     "uint allocated",
```